# Idris2 compiler tries to unify type values unexpectedly

Tags: idris

I hit a compile error in Idris2 that I can't explain, while experimenting with Hoare state monads:

```
data PostS : (valType : Type) -> (stateType : Type) -> (valType -> stateType -> Type) -> Type where
  MkPostS
    :  (val : valType)
    -> (outState : stateType)
    -> {auto 0 prf : prop val outState}
    -> PostS valType stateType prop


mkPost : Nat -> PostS Nat Nat Equal
mkPost s2 = MkPostS s2 s2

f : (s1 : Nat) -> {auto 0 prf : Equal 0 s1} -> PostS Nat Nat (Equal)
f inState {prf} = MkPostS 7 7
```

the compiler complains it cannot unify `inState` and `7` in the right hand side of `f`, which indeed it should not be able to do, but I wouldn't expect it to try either.

The weird part is that replacing the right hand side of `f` with `mkPost 7` *does* compile without error, as does using a similar lambda function. I'm at a loss about what is happening here.

EDIT: a few more experiments

as @joel points out

```
f : PostS Nat Nat (Equal)
f = MkPostS 7 7
```

Also fails, trying to unify 7 and 0, similarly, defining

```
seven : Nat
seven = 7
```

has the same result, but:

```
f' : (s1 : Nat) -> PostS Nat Nat (\n => Equal (s1 + n))
f' s1 = MkPostS 7 (s1+7)
```

works. This initially led me to believe this was a problem originating in the ambiguity for the type of `7`, but no:

```
data Foo = Bar | Baz

f'' : PostS Foo Foo (Equal)
f'' = MkPostS Baz Baz
```

Works, unifying `Baz` with `Baz`, and trying to unify `Bar` and `Baz` fails as expected, **but** `MkPostS Bar Bar` results in "Mismatch between: Baz and Bar", which also goes away when specifying `{prf=Refl}`.

I'm starting to believe there is a bug in the compiler/typechecker.

Comment: curiously, if I remove the `s1` parameter from `f`, I get "Mismatch between: 0 and 7."

Comment: it compiles if I add `{prf=Refl}` to `MkPostS` in `f` but I'd expect Idris to infer that

Comment: Ah, yes, MyHoareMonad is indeed unnecessary, only just realized that myself. Will edit the post.